# Trying to fill a cell reference dynamically within excel

Tags: excel, function, dynamic

I currently have a function that I am trying to apply individually to each row of a very large column of data. The data set is too large to feasibly drag the selection down to increment the cell reference so what I am attempting is to paste the same function into all the appropriate adjacent cells and have the cell reference populate in the function dynamically.

I thought I could do it by using the `INDIRECT` function by using `INDIRECT("A"+ROW())` however this is throwing a !#Value error.

Comment: Change the `+` to a `&`, but I do not understand why simply using `=A1` and copying to the whole range will not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select your formula cell and double-click on the little black square at the lower right hand corner:
[image]

This will repeat the formula into each of the rows below (as long as there is data in the adjacent cells).

Comment: Sometimes I like to over complicate things apparently.